# What is the difference between uniform() and triangular()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, methods, floating-point

As far as i've understood, the random module has a set of methods, among which both uniform() and triangular() return a random float number between two given parameters. Is there no difference between them? Is there any specific case in which we should use one over the other?

Comment: If you throw a single die, you use a uniform distribution. Each outcome 1 ... 6 has the same probability. If you throw a pair of dice, you use a triangular distribution. 2 (1 + 1) and 12 (6 + 6) have much lower probability than 7 (1 + 6, 2 + 5, 3 + 4, 4 + 3, 5 + 2, 6 + 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Documentation

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) is your friend

> random.uniform(a, b)
> Return a random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.
>
> The end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding in the equation a + (b-a) * random().
>
> random.triangular(low, high, mode)
> Return a random floating point number N such that low <= N <= high and with the specified mode between those bounds. The low and high bounds default to zero and one. The mode argument defaults to the midpoint between the bounds, giving a symmetric distribution

---

### Difference

So `random.triangular` models a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Business_simulations) which has strong similarities to a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution).

The main difference in the usage of the methods is the `mode` argument of `random.triangular` which provides more a granular level of control over the distribution.

For a regular `Uni(a,b)` distribution, you should probably use `random.uniform`. According to Wiki, even when the mode is set to 0, a triangular distribution *is not* the same as a uniform distribution

> This distribution for a = 0, b = 1 and c = 0 is the distribution of X = |X1 − X2|, where X1, X2 are two independent random variables with standard uniform distribution.

So `random.triangular` should be used precisely for using triangular distributions.

---

### Example

Here is a simple example highlighting the differences/similarities of both methods

```
import random


# Set Seed for reproducibility
random.seed(123)

# Parameters
lo: int = 0
hi: int = 100
mode: int = 10
sample_size: int = int(1e+6)

# Samples
uni = (random.uniform(lo, hi) for _ in range(sample_size))
tri1 = (random.triangular(lo, hi, mode) for _ in range(sample_size))
tri2 = (random.triangular(lo, hi) for _ in range(sample_size))


# Printing averages
print(round(sum(uni) / sample_size, 2))
# 50.01
print(round(sum(tri1) / sample_size, 2))
# 36.68
print(round(sum(tri2) / sample_size, 2))
# 50.0
```